# Не находит класс

Tags: php, codeigniter

Только начал изучать CodeIgniter,

набираю http://localhost/ci/blog.php
в папке application/controllers/ лежит blog.php , где

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index ()
    {
        echo 'Hello world';
    }
}
```

В браузере попытался вызвать:  The requested URL /ci/blog.php was not found on this server.
 Стоит Денвер, работает, если просто вызывать http://localhost/ci/, то появляется Welcome to CodeIgniter!, где у меня ошибка? 
Спасибо

Comment: мб надо так:

    http://localhost/ci/blog

т.е без расширения. Обычно контроллеры так и работают.

Comment: тоже самое, но кажется ведь все равно, 

спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
http://localhost/ci/index.php/blog
```

Может так ?

Comment: Обалдеть!Работает, а почему так работает?
Спасибо